# Bind Stepper value with Label text in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, binding

I have a ListView, and there are Label and Stepper in one ListView.ItemTemplate. How do I bind Stepper value changing to this Label?

```
<ListView x:Name="productsList"
          ItemsSource="products"
          HasUnevenRows="true">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout x:Name="productStack" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label x:Name="NameLabel"
                       Text="{Binding DisplayName}"
                       Font="Bold" />

                <Label x:Name="count" 
                       Text="1"/>

                <Stepper x:Name="countStepper"
                         Minimum="1"
                         Increment="1" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>    
</ListView>
```

When I try to change Label's text in code behind

```
void countStepper_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    count.Text = countStepper.Value.ToString();
}
```

it is said that `count` does not exist in the current context

Comment: Codebehind of what file? I think you are in the wrong codebehind file. you have to create a class of type ViewCell and put your ViewCell code in there. In the codebehind you have access to NameLabel, count and countStepper. I think you are working in the codebehind of the page

Comment: You cannot access an element inside the view cell of a list view by giving the name property and accessing it in code behind

Comment: @hashimks Is that because these elements are in the template?

Comment: Yes... its a list view and the templates will load based on the number of items binded, so list view will not be able to identify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you can achieve is through below steps, if you are using MVVM

1. Have a model property for Label which displays the count.
2. In the countStepper_ValueChanged, get the object (model data) associated with that view cell and in the view model, code it to set/change the count property of label based on the value change.